# How can I run c# in VS code

Tags: c#, json, .net, visual-studio-code, configuration

When I want to run c# code in VS code, settings.json file opens automatically. Which configuration do I have to write in settings.json file for running c# code?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open VS Code and click "extension" from right side and write c#. When you install that plugin you will be able to use c# in VS Code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I installed c#.  When I run c# code, it asks me to select environment. I select .Net5 and .Net Core then settings.json file open automatically